# aspnet mvc page getting crashed after few minutes on unused

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a basic aspnet project and I have a new layout page where the views use that layout. But sometimes if I leave the page unused .

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/Dashboard_Company.cshtml": "Scripts".
>   Detalhes da Exceção: System.Web.HttpException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/Dashboard_Company.cshtml": "Scripts".

Origin:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/Dashboard_Company.cshtml": "Scripts".]
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.VerifyRenderedBodyOrSections() +672
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +319
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98
>      System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.b__0(TextWriter writer) +232
>      System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +80
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +63
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +237
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98
>      System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
>      System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__4() +198
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9849993
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

And in my Layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/inputmask")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

I'm not sure what it is, if its only happen because it is no a release.

Comment: what do you mean leave the page unused? could you post the view code ?

Comment: I open the view and not doing nothing for awhile.